# .htaccess rewrite with codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I've got a codeigniter setup where all URLs redirect to index.php, like below.

I need /api/index.php to go to /api, but NOT through a redirect.

My code below matches api/index.php but it is still not working.

/index.php/api works fine, and goes to the correct URL, however /api/index.php just goes to a 404 error page... Any suggestions? Am I being silly?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^api/index.php$ /index.php/api [L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|assets)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: The title is misleading. I'd call this *rewrite* rather than *redirect*. They're completely different.

Comment: Use 'L,QSA' instead of L only. also may be you can try adding escaping the slash on th uri.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because it is looking for a file named /api/index.php

Add these Rewrite Conditions

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
//Your rewrite rule here
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```